# Python multiple inheritance from class and protocol

Tags: python, inheritance, protocols

In Python, I have two protocols, one of which inherits from the other:

```
class SupportsFileOperations(Protocol):
    ...

class SupportsMediaOperations(SupportsFileOperations):
    ...
```

I then have a couple of concrete classes that implement these protocols, and one inherits from the other.

```
class File(SupportsFileOperations):
    ...

class MediaFile(File, SupportsMediaOperations):
    def __init__(self):
        File.__init__(self)
```

My question is, is calling `File.__init__(self)` in the `MediaFile` constructor the correct way to initialize this? I'm not sure how multiple inheritance works with protocols.

Thanks!

Comment: What is a `Protocol` in this context? What library is the object from?

Comment: Sorry, this is using `from typing import Protocol`

Comment: Since I stumbled across this question via Google, I am not sure you are using the term "multiple inheritance" correctly. IMHO, "multiple inheritance" is inheriting from multiple base classes at once. What you describe is IMHO called "multilevel inheritance". (Note that Jean-Francois T.'s answer uses multiple inheritance to solve your multilevel-inheritance problem.)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add `Protocol` in the child class:

```py
from typing import Protocol

class SupportsFileOperations(Protocol):
    ...

class SupportsMediaOperations(SupportsFileOperations, Protocol):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

When you using protocols in Python you use structural subtyping, so you don't have to inherit the protocol classes. If you want some class to be considered as a subtype of your protocol you just need to implement all methods of protocol with the same function signatures.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).